# jQuery each returning only last element, Google charts API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I've the following code which will take an array and append to the page dynamically a QR code with the text being an element in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var list = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'hippo', 'ox'];
            var qrUrl = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?';

            //functions
            function getQrCodes(array) {

                $.each(array, function (ix, val) {
                    //options gets chl property redefined for each element
                    //in the array
                    var options = {
                        cht: 'qr',
                        chs: '300x300',
                        chl: array[ix]
                    }
                    qrOptionArray.push(options);
                    console.log('this qr should be: ' + array[ix]);
                    console.log(qrUrl + $.param(options));
                    var $img = $('img').attr('src', qrUrl + $.param(options)).appendTo('body');

                });

            }

            getQrCodes(list);
        });
```

You can see the console output from the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RAmV8/) although for some reason the QR codes don't appear in the fiddle window, they do on my local machine.  The problem I've got is that the last regardless of the fact that you can see the console output change for each element in the array, the only QR code I get is the last element in the array repeated X number of times. [image]  Each of those QR cans will scan and print 'ox', even though the console output is correct.  What's going on here?

Comment: You're selecting **all images**, changing the source, and moving them to the body, **on each iteration**. Sounds like a logic error to me. That or syntax.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because `$('img')` selects images instead of creating them. Once I fixed that, it appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/tHP9v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector where you `append` the image to the body is wrong. You are selecting all existing `img` elements, whereas you want to create a new one. Try this:

```
var $img = $('<img />').attr('src', qrUrl + $.param(options)).appendTo('body');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RAmV8/1/)

Note: `$('<img />')` not `$('img')`.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I did the same damn thing the other day. Thanks, I was beginning to scratch my head a little :)